# New QFontDialog for each QFont?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I change different fonts for 2 (or more) QFont, if I have only one QFontDialog? How can I do it more efficient? Creating new QFontDialog for each QFont will be very stupid, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this simultaneously, you need to add two QFontDialog to your form. Otherwise you can use the one QFontDialog object and simply set current font using `setCurrentFont()` before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

So, creating QFontDialog for each QFont isn't optimal method (too many - over 100 - QFont-s and QFontDialog-s will take a lot of memory). More efficient - creating specific SIGNAL-S and SLOT-s for QFontDialog and QFont (in my situation it is FontChooser (modified QLineEdit), that recieve QFont info from QFontDialog) like this below:

```
QObject::connect(&fontdialog, SIGNAL(font_selected(FontChooser *, const QFont &)), &fontchooser, SLOT(set_font_info(FontChooser *, const QFont &))); 
QObject::connect(&fontchooser, SIGNAL(clicked(FontChooser *, const QFont &)), &fontdialog, SLOT(show(FontChooser *, const QFont &)));
```

When I posted this question, I thought, that Qt have some easy func-s to do that. May be I am wrong? :)
Problem was solved. Thx.